# read from serial port using mavlink protocol with qt c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to read from ardupilot that using mavlink protocol for sending data. if you visit this site:

http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/start

you can find how mavlink protocol works and what I'm trying to do. at the bottom of the site you can see the header's bytes arrangement.
I wrote some code and it's works correctly but after running for a while runtime error appears. as far as I know this errors are about memory allocations but I can't find where I allocate memory illegally.

Here is my reader thread code:

```
QByteArray header;
quint8 ID;
QByteArray payload;
QSerialPort *serial;

void mThread::run()
{//1
    while(serial->isOpen())
    {//2
       if(serial->bytesAvailable() >= 200)
       {//3

           this->msleep(1);
           header = serial->read(1);
           if(header.contains(254))
           {//4
               this->msleep(5);
               header.append(serial->read(5));
               if((header[3] == 1) && (header[4] == 1))
               {//5
                   ID = header[5];
                   msleep(12);
                   payload = serial->read(header[1]);
                   emit updated(payload , ID);
                   payload.clear();
                   header.clear();
               }//5
               else
               {//6
                   header.clear();
               }//6
           }//4
           else
           {//7
               header.clear();
           }//7
       }//3
    }//2
}//1
```

I'm using qt5 whit ubuntu 14.04
and I should mention that I'm reading data with 115200baud and it should manage with thread. If not reading from it will lock my ui.

Comment: if `header` is NULL, `header[3]` will generate a null reference exception, you should check if `header` is `NULL`

Comment: how header can be null? It should have 6bytes then I try to access for example header[3]. am I missing something?

Comment: I check if it's contains 254 then I start reading  more bytes. how can it be null?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need all those msleeps... Reading at that baud rate I would think your serial port input buffer would overflow pretty quickly. Might be worth the time to have a look at it.

As a complete different approach why not use the [MAVlink generator](http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/generator) to generate a library that you could use. This way it saves you from the trouble of parsing the messages and error checking them and all that...